# How To get Many string between two specific characters in Javascript

Tags: javascript, regex

i have a string that like this:

```
> --HeadAny Characters and String this String--/Head
```

i want to get **Any Characters and String this String**

i write this code but not get this string and get null value

```
NewString = MainString.match("--Head(.*?)--/Head");
```

New Update:

I Used This Regex and Worked but if MyString Content Character Code like**(\r \t \n)** this Regex Not Worked And Get Null Value.

```
var regex = new RegExp("\-{2}Head(.*?)\/\-{2}Head");   
var match = regex.exec(MyString);
```

Comment: You passed a string not a regex.

Comment: how to send a regex for this string?

Comment: You can pass regex literal or use the RegExp constructor. See https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Regular_Expressions

Comment: `/--Head(.*?)--\/Head/` instead.

Comment: @elclanrs: Doesn't matter. [Any non-regex object gets parsed with `new RegExp(regexp)`](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/5.1/#sec-15.5.4.10), and the example works in FF 28 and IE 11. OP should provide the complete code he uses.

Comment: @Zeta: read it, good point, still looks a bit confusing I suppose.

Comment: [h2ooooooo](http://stackoverflow.com/users/247893/h2ooooooo) your code not worked

Comment: @HapyUser Don't put them in quotes. `.match(/--Head(.*?)--\/Head/);`

Comment: @h2ooooooo i used this code but not work and get null value;

Comment: @h2ooooooo I Used This 
NewString = MainString.match(/--Head(.*?)--\/Head/);
Also I Use this regex :
var fpattern = new RegExp("--Head");
var lpattern = new RegExp("--\/head");
var betwpattern = new RegExp("(.*?)");
NewString = MainString.match(fpattern+betwpattern+lpattern);
but not worked this

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this:

```
"--HeadAny Characters and String this String--/Head".replace(/--Head(.+)--\/.*/,"$1");
```

In short:

```
string.replace(/--Head(.+)--\/.*/,"$1");
```